# Cannot get response and data is not sent to mongoDB NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am developing an api for my web application. I am making this for social media application.
I have connected MongoDb already and it is fine . But when i send the request , it takes so much time and at the end it failed.  Here is the auth.js file

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const User = require("../models/User");

//Register
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
     const newUser = new User({
         username: req.body.username,
         email: req.body.email,
         password: req.body.password,
     });

     try{
       const user = await newUser.save();
       res.status(200).json(user);
     } catch(err){
         console.log(err);
     }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Here is the User.js file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
        min:3,
        max:20,
        unique:true
    },
    email:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
        max:50,
        unique:true
    },
    password:{
        type:String,
        require:true,
        min:6
    },
    profilePicture:{
        type:String,
        default:""
    },
    coverPicture:{
        type:String,
        default:""
    },
    followers:{
        type:Array,
        default:[]
    },
    followings:{
        type:Array,
        default:[]
    },
    isAdmin:{
        type:Boolean,
        default:false
    }
},
{timestamps:true}
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User",UserSchema);
```

When I sent a Post request by postaman to this

```
http://localhost:8800/api/auth/register
```

There is no response.
In the terminal it shows following error

```
MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Banchi\Desktop\ReactTest\moodfix-api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:149:23)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:555:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:498:7)
::1 - - [19/Sep/2021:10:44:15 +0000] "POST /api/auth/register HTTP/1.1" - -
```

and data is not sent to the mondoDB.

What goes wrong here ?

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with your code. How are you connecting to mongo?

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code. Please make sure that there is a project created and the specific collection is creted for the project in MongoDB.